# clam-NetworkEditor fails to compile

Tags: c++, c

When I try to compile Clam-NetworkEditor-1.4.0 I get these errors:

In file included from src/widgets/generated/moc_QFirstPerson.cxx:10:0:
src/widgets/generated/../QFirstPerson.hxx:348:15: error: function definition does not declare parameters
src/widgets/generated/../QFirstPerson.hxx: In member function ‘virtual void QFirstPerson::paintScene()’:
src/widgets/generated/../QFirstPerson.hxx:202:21: error: ‘((QFirstPerson*)this)->QFirstPerson::sphere’ cannot be used as a function
src/widgets/generated/../QFirstPerson.hxx: In member function ‘void QFirstPerson::drawLight(float*, float*, const char*, const QColor&)’:
src/widgets/generated/../QFirstPerson.hxx:231:20: error: ‘((QFirstPerson*)this)->QFirstPerson::sphere’ cannot be used as a function
scons: *** [src/widgets/generated/generated/moc_QFirstPerson.os] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.

Here is the code from QFirstPerson.hxx

```
#ifndef QFirstPerson_hxx
#define QFirstPerson_hxx

#include <QtOpenGL/QGLWidget>
#undef GetClassName
#include <QtGui/QKeyEvent>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <GL/glu.h>
static float * vColor(const QColor & color)
{
        static float vcolor[4];
        vcolor[0]=color.redF();
        vcolor[1]=color.greenF();
        vcolor[2]=color.blueF();
        vcolor[3]=color.alphaF();
        return vcolor;
}
class Light
{
        unsigned _index;
        QColor _ambient;
        QColor _specular;
        QColor _diffuse;
        float _position[4];
        float _direction[4];
        int _cutoff;
        float _exponent;
        bool _enabled;
public:
    Light(unsigned index,
    float * position, float * direction,
    int cutoff,
    float exponent,
    const QColor & diffuse=Qt::white,
    const QColor & specular=Qt::white,
    const QColor & ambient=Qt::black)
    : _index(index)
    , _ambient(ambient)
    , _specular(specular)
    , _diffuse(diffuse)
    , _cutoff(cutoff)
    , _exponent(exponent)
    , _enabled(true)
{
    for (unsigned i=0; i<4; i++) _position[i]=position[i];
    for (unsigned i=0; i<4; i++) _direction[i]=direction[i];
}
void place()
{
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_AMBIENT, vColor(_ambient));
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_DIFFUSE, vColor(_diffuse));
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_SPECULAR, vColor(_specular));
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, _direction);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_POSITION, _position);
    glLighti (GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, _cutoff);
    glLightf (GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, _exponent);
    glLightf (GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, 1.0f);
    glLightf (GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.2f);
    glLightf (GL_LIGHT0+_index, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, 0.0f);
    (*(_enabled? &glEnable:&glDisable) )(GL_LIGHT0+_index);
}
};

class QFirstPerson : public QGLWidget
{
        double _viewX;
        double _viewY;
        double _viewRotation;
        double _viewElevation;
        double _sourceX;
        double _sourceY;
        double _sphere; 
        GLUquadric * sphere;
        Q_OBJECT
public:
QFirstPerson(QWidget * parent=0)
    : QGLWidget(parent)
    , _viewX(0)
    , _viewY(-1)
    , _viewRotation(0)
    , _viewElevation(0)
    , _sourceX(0)
    , _sourceY(0)
    , _sphere(0)
{
}
void initializeGL()
{
    std::cout << "init" << std::endl;
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    bool blend = true;
    if (blend) glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    bool ligth = true;
    if (ligth) glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
}
void resizeGL(int width, int height)
{
    std::cout << "resize" << std::endl;
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(90.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.01f, 1250.0f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
void paintGL()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glPushMatrix();
    glRotatef( -_viewElevation, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    glRotatef(180-_viewRotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    glTranslatef(-_viewX, 0, -_viewY); // y is at z
    placeLights();
    paintScene();
    glPopMatrix();
    glDepthFunc(GL_NONE);
    paintDecoration();
}
virtual void placeLights()
{
    glLightModelfv(GL_LIGHT_MODEL_AMBIENT, vColor("#505060"));
    static GLfloat position0[] = { 0.0f, 1.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    static GLfloat direction0[] = { 0.0f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    Light light0(0, position0, direction0, 90, 2, "#555", "#555", "#555");
    light0.place();
    static GLfloat position1[] = { -5.0f, 1.0f, 5.0f, 1.0f };
    static GLfloat direction1[] = { .5f, -.5f, -.5f, 1.0f };
    Light light1(1, position1, direction1, 90, 2, "#700", "#770", "#700");
    light1.place();
    static GLfloat position2[] = { 5.0f, 1.0f, -5.0f, 1.0f };
    static GLfloat direction2[] = { -1.0f/5, -1.0f/5, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    Light light2(2, position2, direction2, 90, 2, "#077", "#007", "#077");
    light2.place();
    drawLight(position0, direction0, "Light0", "#777");
    drawLight(position1, direction1, "Light1", "#a00");
    drawLight(position2, direction2, "Light2", "#0aa");
}
void roomWall(float bottom, float top)
{
    glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
    for (unsigned i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(10.f-i,top,10.f);
        glVertex3f(10.f-i,bottom,10.f);
    }
    for (unsigned i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(-10.f,top,10.f-i);
        glVertex3f(-10.f,bottom,10.f-i);
    }
    for (unsigned i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(-10.f+i,top,-10.f);
        glVertex3f(-10.f+i,bottom,-10.f);
    }
    for (unsigned i=0; i<20; i++)
    {
        glVertex3f(10.f,top,-10.f+i);
        glVertex3f(10.f,bottom,-10.f+i);
    }
    glVertex3f(10.f,top,10.f);
    glVertex3f(10.f,bottom,10.f);
    glEnd();
}
virtual void paintScene()
{
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, vColor("white"));
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, vColor("white"));
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, vColor("#333"));
    glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, 0);
    glColor4fv(vColor(Qt::white));
    roomWall(-1.75, -1);
    roomWall(-1, 0);
    roomWall(0, 1);
    roomWall(1, 1.75);
    qglColor(Qt::yellow);
    drawPlane(-1.75);
    glColor4fv(vColor("#aaa"));
    drawPlane(+1.75);
    qglColor(QColor("#ffa"));
    renderText(0., 1, 10.-1, "North (+Y)");
    renderText(0., 1, -10.+1, "South (-Y)");
    renderText(10.-1, 1, 0., "East (+X)");
    renderText(-10.+1, 1, 0., "West (-X)");
    glPushMatrix();
        glColor4fv(vColor("#b22"));
        glTranslatef(_sourceX,0,_sourceY);
        renderText(0., 1, 0., "Source");
        glBegin(GL_LINES);
            glVertex3f(0.,1.,0.);
            glVertex3f(0.,0.,0.);
        glEnd();
        gluSphere(sphere(), 0.5f, 40, 20);
    glPopMatrix();
}
void drawPlane(float height)
{
    for (unsigned j=0; j<20; j++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUAD_STRIP);
        for (unsigned i=0; i<=20; i++)
        {
            glVertex3f(10.f-j,height,10.f-i);
            glVertex3f(10.f-(j+1),height,10.f-i);
        }
        glEnd();
    }
}
void drawLight(float * position, float * direction, const char * label, const QColor & color)
{
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor4fv(vColor(color));
    glTranslatef(position[0],position[1],position[2]);
    renderText(0., 2, 0., label);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, vColor(color));
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
        glVertex3f(0.,0.,0.);
        glVertex3fv(direction);
        glVertex3f(0.,2.,0.);
        glVertex3f(0.,0.,0.);
    glEnd();
    gluSphere(sphere(), 0.2f, 40, 20);
    glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_EMISSION, vColor("black"));
    glPopMatrix();
}
virtual void paintDecoration()
{
    glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    QString emiterString = tr("Emitter: %1, %2")
            .arg(QString::number(_sourceX,'d',2))
            .arg(QString::number(_sourceY,'d',2))
            ;
    QString receiverString = tr("Receiver: %1, %2 angle %3")
            .arg(QString::number(_viewX,'d',2))
            .arg(QString::number(_viewY,'d',2))
            .arg(QString::number(_viewRotation,'d',0))
            ;
    glColor4fv(vColor("black"));
    renderText(10,20, receiverString);
    renderText(10,40, emiterString);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0,.06,-.1);
    glVertex3f(0,.02,-.1);
    glVertex3f(0,-.06,-.1);
    glVertex3f(0,-.02,-.1);
    glVertex3f(.06,0,-.1);
    glVertex3f(.02,0,-.1);
    glVertex3f(-.06,0,-.1);
    glVertex3f(-.02,0,-.1);
    glEnd();
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
void keyPressEvent( QKeyEvent * event)
{
    std::cout << "key" << std::endl;
    float cosOrientation = std::cos(_viewRotation*M_PI/180.f);
    float sinOrientation = std::sin(_viewRotation*M_PI/180.f);
    bool strafe = event->modifiers() & Qt::AltModifier;
    bool run = event->modifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier;
    float step = run ? .4f : .1f;
    switch (event->key())
    {
        case Qt::Key_Left:
            if (strafe)
            {
                _viewX += cosOrientation * step;
                _viewY -= sinOrientation * step;
                emitPositionChange();
            }
            else
            {
                _viewRotation+=10;
                emit orientationChanged(_viewRotation);
            }
        break;
        case Qt::Key_Right:
            if (strafe)
            {
                _viewX -= cosOrientation * step;
                _viewY += sinOrientation * step;
                emitPositionChange();
                emit posChanged(QPointF(_viewX, _viewY));
            }
            else
            {
                _viewRotation-=10;
                emit orientationChanged(_viewRotation);
            }
        break;
        case Qt::Key_PageUp:
            _viewElevation+=10;
        break;
        case Qt::Key_PageDown:
            _viewElevation-=10;
        break;
        case Qt::Key_Up:
            _viewX += sinOrientation * step;
            _viewY += cosOrientation * step;
            emitPositionChange();
        break;
        case Qt::Key_Down:
            _viewX -= sinOrientation * step;
            _viewY -= cosOrientation * step;
            emitPositionChange();
        break;
        case Qt::Key_A:
            _sourceX+=step;
        break;
        case Qt::Key_D:
            _sourceX-=step;
        break;
        case Qt::Key_W:
            _sourceY+=step;
        break;
        case Qt::Key_S:
            _sourceY-=step;
        break;
        case Qt::Key_Escape:
            close();
        break;
        default:
            event->ignore();
            return;
        return;
    }
    while (_viewRotation>=360.f) _viewRotation-=360.f;
    while (_viewRotation<0.f) _viewRotation+=360.f;
    event->accept();
    updateGL();
}
signals:
        double posChanged(QPointF point);
        double xPosChanged(double x);
        double yPosChanged(double y);
        double orientationChanged(double degrees);
private:
    GLUquadric * sphere
    {
    if (!_sphere) _sphere = gluNewQuadric();
    return _sphere;
    }
    void emitPositionChange()
    {
    emit posChanged(QPointF(_viewX, _viewY));
    emit xPosChanged(_viewX);
    emit yPosChanged(_viewY);
    }
};


#endif// QFirstPerson_hxx
```

Answer (score 1):

You have this declaration

```
class QFirstPerson : public QGLWidget
{
        double _viewX;
        double _viewY;
        double _viewRotation;
        double _viewElevation;
        double _sourceX;
        double _sourceY;
        double _sphere; 
        GLUquadric * sphere;   // <--
```

But later this code

```
gluSphere(sphere(), 0.5f, 40, 20);
```

Which assumes that `sphere` is callable. The compiler disagrees.

Comment: Thanks you for such a quick reply. I'm not a programmer so how do I fix it?

Comment: I don't know Qt well enough to tell. The compiler says that the two lines are in conflict, but I don't know which one is wrong.